# phpBB integration to site - How to synchronize session?

Tags: php, phpbb3

I've integrated phpBB into my website. When user log on or register to my site one will be
automatically log in to phpbb forum also. My issue is that the user get logout from the
forum very faster than my site. How can i synchronize the logout time with my site?

the following are my settings given in forum. site available in `sitename.com.au/beta`

```
Cookie settings
Cookie domain: .sitename.com.au
Cookie name:  phpbb_brmra
Cookie path: /

Server settings
Domain name: .sitename.com.au
Script path:: /beta/Forum
```

Answer (score 1):

When you go to the Administration Control Panel, under the tab `General` there's (almost at the bottom) a section called `Load Settings`. There you can specify the length of a session in phpBB3.

Comment: i set it to a large value, 200000 . but still no luck